# How to understand android Service?

Tags: android, service

I am newbe of android,and I am confused about android service,according my understanding,UI-related code run in activity,and background work run in my own thread,so,what's usage of service? It seems I can use activity and thread to do anything.

Answer (score 5):

Background work can and should be run in a thread. However, if that work is not part of a service, the OS may stop that thread without warning if none of the app's activities are visible.

For example, if you write an MP3 player app, you will probably not want the music to stop if the user returns to the home screen. So you make a service that actually plays the music, and then the OS will try to avoid killing your app's process if the service is running.

Services can also be used to provide functionality for other applications. In that case, the app's process will be started on demand when some other app wishes to utilize the service, and may be stopped by the OS once the other apps are finished with the service.

See the [Service Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but If I start a thread in one activity,and then user return to home screen,the thread will stop running?

Comment: The thread may continue running for a while, but the OS will kill the the application without warning if it wants to reclaim the memory. Since it has no visible activity, and no running service, the OS considers the process as just a cache of the application, which can be purged without anybody caring. Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html for more information.